# MySQL XtraBackup Restore Gzip

Tags: mysql

I have backed up my database using XtraBackup and gziped the output. Tar is misreading the archives:

```
# ls -alh mydb.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96G Feb  1 03:56 my-backup-20170201-001224.tar.gz

# tar tvfz my-backup-20170201-001224.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       263 2017-02-01 00:12 ./backup-my.cnf
```

**How can I extract the complete contents of the XtraBackup?**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
tar xvfi ./my-backup-20170201-001224.tar.gz
```

Apparently the i flag doesn't something here that allows the files to be found.